# DB adapter found on php.net

Tags: php, mysql

I found a db adapter on php.net, on the mysql-connect page.
This is a page viewed quite a lot (I would imagine).

It includes what the author claims is a singleton pattern class.

Found on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Writer says:

> "Here's a singleton class to manage a single Database connection.  The
>   Open method uses constant values as defautls, read from an ini file
>   through an initializer script loaded at the top of each web page.  You
>   can also override the default values by manually entering your own (in
>   case you need to switch servers or database names mid-script). The qry
>   function takes a prepared statement and will return the first row,
>   first associative row, first cell, or entire result set based on the
>   second parameter (entire result if omitted)."
>
> Usage: $DB = DB::Open(); 
>   $result = $DB->qry(" {SQL Statement} ;");

```
<?php
    abstract class Database_Object
    {
        protected static $DB_Name;
        protected static $DB_Open;
        protected static $DB_Conn;

        protected function __construct($database, $hostname, $hostport, $username, $password)
        {
            self::$DB_Name = $database;
            self::$DB_Conn = mysql_connect($hostname . ":" . $hostport, $username, $password);
            if (!self::$DB_Conn) { die('Critical Stop Error: Database Error<br />' . mysql_error()); }
            mysql_select_db(self::$DB_Name, self::$DB_Conn);
        }

        private function __clone() {}

        public function __destruct()
        {
//            mysql_close(self::$DB_Conn);  <-- commented out due to current shared-link close 'feature'.  If left in, causes a warning that this is not a valid link resource.
        }
    }

    final class DB extends Database_Object
    {
        public static function Open($database = DB_NAME, $hostname = DB_HOST, $hostport = DB_PORT, $username = DB_USER,$password = DB_PASS)
        {
            if (!self::$DB_Open)
            {
                self::$DB_Open = new self($database, $hostname, $hostport, $username, $password);
            }
            else
            {
                self::$DB_Open = null;
                self::$DB_Open = new self($database, $hostname, $hostport, $username, $password);
            }
            return self::$DB_Open;
        }

        public function qry($sql, $return_format = 0)
        {
            $query = mysql_query($sql, self::$DB_Conn) OR die(mysql_error());
            switch ($return_format)
            {
                case 1:
                    $query = mysql_fetch_row($query);
                    return $query;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $query = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    return $query;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $query = mysql_fetch_row($query);
                    $query = $query[0];
                    return $query;
                default:
                    return $query;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

After looking at the code I have one question, is this really a singleton (see DB class and Open function)?

What about static properties makes a singleton pattern work ?

Comment: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.

Comment: hi @Chris you are right thanks. Just quite interested in oop principles and singleton pattern. thanks

Comment: A good singleton construct is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994541/php-dont-allow-object-to-instantiate-more-than-once/8994589#8994589
Check it out :)

Comment: thanks alot @Chris taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean, if `self::$DB_Open` DOES exist it sets it to null and creates a new instance of the object anyway.

Appears you are right and this does not seem like the singleton pattern.

Regarding singleton pattern with static properties. Unlike instance variables which are in the **objects scope**, static variables are in **class scope**. 
What this means is that even if you create an object multiple times it will still use the same value for the static property every time. It's what allows them to be great for counters and therefore global singletons.

See the below:

```
Class A {
static int y=1;
int x=3;
}
$newA = new A();
$newB = new A();
$newC = new A();
```

The above creates 3 instances of x. You can make a change in 1 instance and it will only make changes in that 1 Instance.
But only 1 instance of y is created. So a change in 1 and all 3 will change. They all exist in same context. Therefore point to the same value. If you increment one the others will display the same increment ect..

So to re-iterate, even though only a single instance of `DB_Conn` does exist it continually resets it and writes to it again (it does not have to act like this).

To fix the problem the author could return the `self::$DB_Open` property if it does exist.

Comment: ah I see so static variables can be global properties as you can access the same static variable at anytime (like static method) and it points to same value. Thanks